# How to put the autocomplete widget type in my field?

Tags: ajax, entities

i'm new in Drupal and i'm trying to create a field type taxonomy_reference, but i been looking the way to put the widget autocomplete for the field but It doesn't seem to work. This is the code that i'm using to create the field:

```
 $field = array(
    'field_name' => 'new_keyword',
    'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference',

          );

  field_create_field($field);

 $instance = array(
    'field_name' => 'new_keyword',
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'bundle' => 'specimen',
    'label'=> 'Keywords',

  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
```

Where should I put the widget type? Thank you.